# Error when trying to find & replace the qoute sign " with Range.Replace

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro file that split files and names them by specific list The names of the files in this list that contain the quote sign `"` is not getting created and I want to find and replace all of them with regular space in that range only.

But when I run the macro it returns me

> Argument not optional.

Can someone find where is my problem?

```
'Loop for creating files
For i = 2 To FilesCounter
    NewWBName = EmailWS.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

    With SplitWS
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=NewWBName
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  'Copy cells starting from column B
    End With

    With NewWB.Worksheets(1)
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    'find and replace all th " in the WB names list
    With EmailWS
        .Range("$A:$A").Replace What:=""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False"
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = NameForFile & "" & NewWBName
    End With

    NewWB.SaveAs fileName:=DesPath & "\" & NameForFile & "" & NewWBName & ".xlsx", Password:=PassFile
    NewWB.Close

Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"` in VBA can be written as `""""` or `Chr(34)`

`"""` is not the same as `""""`

In the immediate window type this

```
?Chr(34)
"    '<~~ This is what you will get
```

and then this

```
?"""" = Chr(34)
True '<~~ This is what you will get
```

Now try

```
?""" = Chr(34)
```

See what you get :)

In your code, replace `"""` by `""""` or `Chr(34)` so it becomes `What:=""""`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understood you. In the cells I have " just once and not two "". Can you show me inside my code the changes that you would do?

Comment: I already showed it to you :) See the last line in the above post

Comment: THE LAST LINE BECOMES RED WHEN i PASTE THIS

Comment: Yes becuase you have `"` at the end of that line `MatchCase:=False"`... Remove that...